# Updating learning rate with Libtorch 1.5 and optimiser options in C++

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

With the release of the 1.5 stable version of the C++ API for PyTorch, there are some changes in some of the object interfaces. For instance, now

```
optimizer.options.learning_rate();
```

won't work (here the optimiser being used is Adam) since `learning_rate` has changed to `lr` (see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases) but moreover the optimiser no longer has options (`no member named 'options' in 'torch::optim::Adam'`). So my question is: how would one run

```
optimizer.options.learning_rate();
```

or update the learning rate

```
optimizer.options.learning_rate(updatedlearningrate);
```

with the new release? Any help will be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimisers now behave like their Python counterparts and the learning rates need to be set per parameter group.

```cpp
for (auto param_group : optimizer.param_groups()) {
  # Static cast needed as options() returns OptimizerOptions (base class)
  static_cast<torch::optim::AdamOptions &>(param_group.options()).lr(new_lr);
}
```

If you didn't specify separate parameter groups, there will be only a single group and you could directly set its learning rate as suggested in [Issue #35640 - How do you change Adam learning rate since the latest commits?](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/35640#issuecomment-605953263):

```cpp
static_cast<torch::optim::AdamOptions &>(optimizer.param_groups()[0].options()).lr(new_lr)
```